# What can I do to remedy Ubuntu 18.04 lag (cursor lag, window lag, screen glitches)?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, amd-graphics, wayland

I have an HP Laptop 15-bw0xx and I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04.1.

My system specs are:

- Memory 6GiB,
- Processor AMD r7 12 compute cores 4c+8g × 4,
- Graphics AMD/ATI Carrizo (rev c8) Radeon R7.

I've already disabled the "animations" and I have installed the AMD proprietary drivers.

My GUI/DE (gnome, wayland) keeps lagging frequently, the cursor and the windows freeze for some seconds and it feels bumpy and almost unusable. A couple of snaps and programs have already started crashing. I even have glitches and weird colors on the screen sometimes. CPU and RAM usage seems totally normal on [system monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOegg.png).

I had been using Ubuntu with Unity up until 16.04 recently and it was great, everything was as smooth as butter. Ubuntu 18.04 feels like it refuses to work with my system for reasons I cannot understand.

What is the cause of this (newfound) lag?
And what can I do about it?

**EDIT 1**

After applying the changes suggested in the comments below, ubuntu won't load (blank screen after the ubuntu logo) and I was met with this screen: 
https://imgur.com/a/qrANql

**EDIT 2**

Couldn't solve the problem. Reverted back to 16.04. Hope ubuntu with gnome improves its performance until 2021.

Comment: Can you try Xorg instead of Wayland to see if the lag is the same?

Comment: Thank you, but how do I do that? Do I simply choose ubuntu without wayland  from the login screen? Do I need to install Xorg?

Comment: Both Xorg and Wayland should already be installed. Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and uncomment the line `WaylandEnable=false`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that you need to do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and then reboot.

Comment: Unfortunately now, I cannot boot into ubuntu. After the ubuntu logo, something (possibly related to the gpu or the dpkg-reconfigure command) crashes, the screen goes blank and I never see the login prompt.

Comment: Can you get to tty cli login using ctrl-alt-F3? I you can, you can login and modify the login greeter to lightdm, do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and select `lightdm`, ok, then reboot.